# String not being accepted as a valid parameter for a function (C++)

Tags: c++, string

I'm trying to use the following code but I keep getting a C2061
error and a syntax error about identifier 'string'.

The compiler understands strings, as I could set a string variable and ask it to output it. I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio.

```
#define <iostream>
#define <string>
using namespace std;

void somefunction(string x, int y) {
    // some code here using x and y
}
```

Comment: Please post your code and error(s) here as text. See: how to create a [mcve]

Comment: Are you sure `#define` is the correct preprocessor command to use there?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `#include` instead of `#define`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void somefunction(string x, int y) {
    // some code here using x and y
}
```